# Pulling data from sql database into textfield

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a table of students and i wanted to show the name of the student on the profile page which is stored in the students table.

This is what i have in mind for my controller:

```
public ActionResult StudentName(StudentModel model)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        using (var db = new SchoolDataContext())
        {
            var result = from s in db.Students select s.StudentName;
            model.StudentName = result.ToString();
        }
     }
}
```

in my view i have:

```
@Html.LabelFor(s => s.StudentName)
@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.StudentName)
```

my model:

```
public class StudentModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Student Name")]
    public string StudentName{ get; set; }
}
```

I will need a get method to get the student name to display in the textbox and at the same time have a post method so that it could be saved if changed within the same box after clicking save.

Comment: I don't see a question here

Comment: @Forty-Two i wanted to know if i am write or not for what i have in my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your controller would look something like this:

```
public ActionResult StudentName(int studentId)//you can't pass a model object to a get request
{
        var model = new StudentModel();
        using (var db = new SchoolDataContext())
        {
            //fetch your record based on id param here.  This is just a sample...
            var result = from s in db.Students
                         where s.id equals studentId 
                         select s.StudentName.FirstOrDefault();
            model.StudentName = result.ToString();
        }
     return View(model);
}
```

In the get above, you can pass in an id and then fetch the record from the database.  Populate your model properties with the data retrieved and pass that model into your view.

Then in the post action below, you accept the model as an argument, check the model state, and process the data.  I'm showing a redirect here, but you can return any view you'd like after the post executes.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult StudentName(StudentModel model)
{
     if(ModelState.IsValid)
     {
        using (var db = new SchoolDataContext())
        {
            //update your db record
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
     return View(model);

}
```

Comment: I am trying this right now but i wanted to know (int studentId) that i pass in the get - where will it be getting the id to compare with the id in the database?

Comment: My Action method is not being hit and i am not sure why - could you possibly take a  second look?

Comment: @072et Change `<button type="button" value="save" />` to `<button type="submit" value="save" />`